# HTML / JavaScript / Textarea - How to find rows value of a resized textarea

Tags: javascript, html

```
<textarea name="some-name" rows="10" cols="60>Some Text inside...</textarea>
```

I resize a textarea (one as shown above) using the drag icon seen at the bottom right of it.

The value of rows attribute remains same (with value 10) after the resize.

My question is: how can I find the new rows value after resizing a textarea control?

Comment: @User863, Not exactly.  The scenario of my question is when you resize the textarea.  That question is very generic.

Comment: very good question, I tried to use .rows but it doesnt work when you do with mouse
however if you use javascript code to change the text area size, then you call the rows it would work fine console.log(document.getElementById("txtArea").attributes["rows"]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lineHeight` and `scrollheight`

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea')

function calculateRows() {
  var lineheight = parseInt(textarea.style.lineHeight) || 12; //line-height: 12px;
  var scrollheight = textarea.scrollHeight;

  console.clear();
  console.log(Math.floor(scrollheight / lineheight));
}

calculateRows()

new ResizeObserver(calculateRows).observe(textarea)
```

```css
#textarea {
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="some-name" rows="10" cols="60" id="textarea"></textarea>
```